# How to easily change monitor settings?

Tags: windows-10, multi-monitor

I am using a Laptop with a resolution of max. 4k. But I often work in environments (clients, presentations etc.) where i can not exploit the max and have to switch to lower display-settings. Sometimes Windows10 even does it automagically for me when  connect an external monitor.

Instead of all these undesired automatism, I'd rather have a way to define some "display profiles" (resolution, scaling/DPI etc.) and then easily switch profiles. Despite Google-ing for long time, I could not find any software to do this. Perhaps I'm using the wrong words but maybe someone could kindly recommend his favorite way to handle this issue. *(I can't be the only one who's annoyed by these things...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the commercial tool [Ultramon](https://www.realtimesoft.com/ultramon/Default.asp), which is at ~40 USD for a single license.

It has

- multi-monitor support
- display profiles with resolution, orientation, color depth, refresh rate, position
- I works on Windows 7 and I found statements about "Windows 8 and later", but Windows 10 wasn't explicitly mentioned

Here's a screenshot from my PC (sorry, German). I have a profile for my normal desktop ("Arbeitsplatz") and one for a meeting room ("Raum III") where the beamer always caused trouble and cut of parts of the picture. Using this profile I can make the beamer display what I want.

[image: Ultramon Screenshot]

This is a configuration screen:

[image: Configuration screen]

It cannot change the DPI settings according to [this post](https://www.realtimesoft.com/multimon/forum/messages.asp?Topic=11870&tmpl=), but that might be a limitation of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the graphics card, such a feature might be built-in. For example, some Intel Graphics cards come with a driver that enables defining profiles.

It has

- multi-monitor support
- display profiles with resolution, orientation, refresh rate, scaling and perhaps even advanced features (not available on my machine)
  I works on all Windows versions for which the driver is released. Typically Intel has good support and Windows 10 is no problem.

Main advantage over a commercial tool: it's free.

Accessing the profiles is a bit tricky:

[image: Intel display profiles]

Here's what a settings dialog looks like:

[image: Intel settings dialog]